# How can use SonarScanner from Jenkins while running on a different server (than Sonar)?

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I use Jenkins for Continuous Integration, and I plan to add SonarQube to its tasks. I know it is possible to run SonarQube server and database remotely from the scanner, thanks to the documentation.

I tried to install sonarqube and sonarscanner plugins in Jenkins, setting up a slave connected to the server hosting sonarqube and sonarscanner, but Jenkins  can't trigger a scan.

I also don't understand how Sonar would get the code ? Is Jenkins supposed to send it all to the server ?
Or do I have to manage the pulling from the repository on the server hosting Sonar ?

Answer (score 0):

You're correct, the scanner must be on the build machine.